# Testing Spring MVC with Mockito

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test-mvc

first of all: I am rather new to Spring.

I have a very simple Spring Boot app with 3 file:
Main App:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingsController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService svc;

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        System.out.println(svc.sayHello());
        return svc.sayHello();
    }
}
```

And a "Service":

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello from the real thing";
    }
}
```

I now want to write an (integration) test where the service (which in my real application would have some DB connection) is mocked. What I have is this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = App.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AppTest
{
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private SomeService svcMock;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(svcMock.sayHello()).thenReturn("Hello from Mock");
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void run() throws Exception {
        MvcResult res = mockMvc.perform(get("/greeting"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
        assertEquals("Hello from Mock", res.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this test fails because the real service is being used during testing and not my mock service. What am I doing wrong? How can I tell the framework to use the Mock service during testing?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

You need separate configurations for production and testing.

The production configuration asks Spring to inject the real class.  The test configuration sneaks in the mock instead.

Lately I've been trying to test without Spring.  I use Mockito and inject manually in my tests.  I leave the bean factory out of it.  That lets me use mocks and makes my tests run faster, because I only instantiate the beans that I need for the test.

Comment: Testing without Spring is generally a good approach to take whenever possible. If you do need to mock beans you might be interested in the `@MockBean` annotation coming in Spring Boot 1.4 (https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4)

Comment: @Phil Webb, thank you.  Love your work with Spring Boot.  We're migrating all our stuff from JBOSS to Pivotal Cloud Foundry.  We've had Spring apps for the past 6 years, but always forced to deploy on JBOSS.  No more in another month or so.